# Available event for connection timeout for streams publishing over RTSP?

Tags: wowza

I use Wowza GoCoder to publish video to a custom Wowza live application. In my application I attach an `IRTSPActionNotify` event listener within the `onRTPSessionCreate` callback. In the `onRecord` callback of my `IRTSPActionNotify` I perform various tasks - start recording the live stream, among other things. In my `onTeardown` callback I then stop the recording and do some additional processing of the recorded video, like moving the video file to a different storage location.

What I just noticed was that if the encoder timeout, due to a lost connection, power failure or some other sudden event, I wont receive an `onTeardown` event - not even when the RTSP session timeout. This is a big issue for me, since I need to do this additional processing before I make the published stream available for on demand view through another application.

I've been browsing through [the documentation](http://www.wowza.com/resources/serverapi/) looking for an event or a utility-class that could help me out, but so far to no avail.

**Is there some reliable event, or other reliable way to know that a connection has timed out, so that I can trigger this processing also for streams that doesn't fire a teardown-event?**

*I first discovered this issue when I lost connection on my mobile device while encoding video using the Wowza GoCoder app for iOS, but I guess the issue would be the same for any encoder.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Wowza modules, I have the following pattern, which proved to be quite reliable so far:

I have a custom worker thread and that iterates over all client types. Now this allows me to keep track of clients, and I have found that eventually all kind of disasters lead to clients being removed from those lists after unclear timeouts.

I think try tracking (add / remove) clients in your own `Set` and see if that is more accurate.

You could also try and see if anything gets called in that case in `IMediaStreamActionNotify2`.

I have seen `onStreamCreate(IMediaStream stream)` and `onStreamDestroy(IMediaStream stream)` being called in `ModuleBase` in case of GoCoder on iOS, and I am attaching an instance of `IMediaStreamActionNotify2` to the stream by calling `stream.addClientListener(actionNotify)`

On the GoCoder platform: I am not sure that it's the same on Android, the GoCoder Android and iOS versions have a fundamental difference, that is the streaming protocol itself, which leads to different API calls and behaviour on backend side. Don't go live without testing on both platforms.. :-)

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising. Useful resources as well! I will give it a try.